# DAAB, do we need to handle connection opening closing manually?

Tags: c#, enterprise-library, daab

I am using DAAB. Plz guide me do we need to check and clsoe connections manually after a db call ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enterprise library takes care of opening and closing connections for you.

You don't need to write code to do this.

A way of using Entlib 5.0 DAAB (without unity or any other dependency injection) is :

```
public DataSet someMethod()
{
    database = new SqlDatabase(connectionString);
    return database.ExecuteDataSet("procName", valparam1, valparam2);
}
```